# Can IIS do same function like Google Analysis?

Tags: iis

In addition to insert a script syntax like Google Analysis into application web site , to determine page  browser views, is there same function it can be set by IIS or otherwise?

Why ask this question because china mainland can't use google analysis.

thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS by default creates some log files, and often they contain many valuable information, including website visit count, date and Visitor's IP address. The log files are created in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles. You can change the location later.

You can use a tool named [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) for parsing the Logs and it has a SQL like syntax for parsing data and could be run from Command Line. [Quick tutorial](http://aspalliance.com/1714_Using_LogParser_22_to_Parse_IIS_Logs_and_Other_Logs).